# Where are files saved when using Google Colab with a Custom GCE VM

Tags: docker, google-colaboratory, google-compute-engine, google-container-optimized-os

I am using Google Colab in combination with a Custom GCE VM based on the instructions [here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/marketplace.html). I now need a way to retrieve files from the VM without using the Colab interface due to a bug described in [this issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3714) and [this issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2880). I've reviewed the answers from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956331/where-are-saved-files-in-google-colab-located) about file storage on hosted instances, but I don't think it helps me in this case.

I've attempted to SSH into the machine to find files, but I can't locate the `/content` directory that I expect to see in `root`. After digging through the file system I found the `/mnt/stateful_partition/var/lib/docker` directory is using the amount of disk space I expect to reflect the size of the data with a file object called `colab-vmdisk` that looks promising. I'm not sure how to proceed, but given the file path I expect there's a docker-based solution here that I don't know.

Comment: Colab notebooks are stored in Google Drive https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#:~:text=Colab%20notebooks%20are%20stored%20in,Google%20Drive%20file%20sharing%20instructions.

Comment: I am specifically looking for the data created by Colab when using the custom GCE VM connection option, not the notebook itself. These are the instructions for connecting Colab to a custom VM https://research.google.com/colaboratory/marketplace.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Colab from GCE is in its own docker container as you found. If you want to access the files in the google colab session, run `docker ps` and copy the container id from the bottom row. As for copying a file over, do `docker cp (your container id):/path/to/google/colab/folder/ /path/to/gce/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @hidude562! I've moved to a different data analysis solution, so haven't been able to validate this answer. Based on the post by @Adrot I'm going to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

@hidude562's answer is on point. It worked for me. I've been trying to figure out a method with good download speeds (as fast as when I was using gdrive with Colab on their hosted runtime)

Colab seems to be managing the entire thing within a docker container, as you rightly mentioned @s_go. It also explains how they keep the popular libraries updated right from the start, including the [gdown](https://pypi.org/project/gdown/4.7.1/) library. I figured it's best to use gdown to download large files into Colab from Gdrive; as google doesnt let you mount your personal gdrive to Colab when using a custom GCE VM runtime, due to some authorisation blockers. This method downloads files into colab at full speed Google is capable of (I've seen upto ~500mbps)

Adding on, after extracting the file from the Docker file, I used FileZilla SFTP to download the file to my local. It was as fast as expected, direct download from the SSH was around ~100kbps for some reason, with FileZilla on the same VM I got download speeds of upto ~13mbps (my wifi dl bandwidth is about ~25mbps)

Hope this comment validates @hidude562's answer for other readers.!

Thank you for your question @s_go and your answer @hidude562!:)

Comment: Thanks for validating! I've not been able to check the answer above, but will accept now.